# how to fix Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java

I created an event using a combobox. in the table. when starting the second line of the table an error appears as shown below. but the program still runs.
what's wrong with my code, please help me.

combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener()  {

public void  itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent e){
       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

```
       @Override
                public void run() {
                      Global.setSalesOrder(false);
                    int row=table.getSelectedRow();
                    int rowcount=table.getRowCount();
                    if(row==-1) {row=1;}

                  if (e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){


                        int select=combo.getSelectedIndex();


                        if(row==-1) {row=1;}
                        //
                        table.setValueAt(Global.getUserID(), row, 11);
                        table.setValueAt(Global.getNow(), row, 13);
                        if(Global.getString(table.getValueAt(row, 10)).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                            table.setValueAt(Global.getUserID(), row, 10);
                            table.setValueAt(Global.getNow(), row, 12);
                        }
                        //
                        String Vselect = new String();
                        if(select<0) select=0;
                       Vselect=combo.getItemAt(select).toString();
                        if(!textField.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                            combo.setSelectedIndex(select);

                        }


                        table.changeSelection(row, 3, false, false);
                        table.editCellAt(row, 3); 
                        String val=combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        try{val=val.substring(0, val.indexOf("|")).trim();}catch(Exception ex){}
                        val=Global.getformat(val);
                        String []attribut=Global.getAttributArtikel(val);
                        //String id=Global.getString(table.getValueAt(row, 14));
                        String it=attribut[0];
                        String price=attribut[1];
                        if(price==null){
                            Global.showMessageDialog("Maaf kode artikel tidak ditemukan!");
                            return;
                        }
```

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Vselect=combo.getItemAt(select).toString();

Comment: I meant, the error log. The trace or error message.

Comment: oh sorry,

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at IvoryUpline.ComboEditorArtikel_SO$2$3.run(SalesOrder.java:2894)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)